# how to limit character to jump only above floor , not on its side area

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

How to prevent my character stop jumping while colliding with my  gameobject tag as a floor. I just want my floor to be used on jumping when my character is above it , not on its side part.

so I have a ground object tagged as floor, I have already implemented a code for preventing my 2D character double jumping and I already put in some physics material 2d friction = 0 to the floor objects (to prevent player and floor stickiness with each other).

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        _canJump = true;
    }
}


private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        _canJump= false;
    }
}
```

but still, when my character collides with a floor object that is scaled similar to a wall and button mashed my space button key (jump input), it can still somehow jump upwards. Is there an easy way to prevent that? thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate the floor from the wall by calculating the angle between the "up" vector and the normal of your collision contact.

The following code counts slopes of up to 45° as floor.

```csharp
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
  {
    if(Vector2.Angle(collision.GetContact(0).normal, Vector2.Up)<45)
    {
      _canJump = true;
    }
  }
}


private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
  if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Floor"))
  {
    if(Vector2.Angle(collision.GetContact(0).normal, Vector2.Up)<45)
    {
      _canJump = false;
    }
  }
}
```